# Origin http://localhost is not allowed... solve without adding to remote server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, cross-domain, screen-scraping

I know about the issues with cross-site requests, and I know there's already questions about this topic here on Stack. However, my question isn't directly answered so therefore I'm posting it here.

So, what I want to do is screen scrape a site, with AJAX. However, I get this message...

```
Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

...and I know of different solutions to this. However, all the solutions I know of (e.g JSONP) includes adding stuff to the remote server, which isn't possible in this case.

So, what I wonder is if it's possible to come around this issue without adding something on the remote server, and if so what that is. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Someone refresh my memory. Doesn't JSONP work because the cross-site rule does not apply to loading of scripts? If so, is there a way to pretend you are loading a script from the scrapee site? Perhaps with help from your own server.

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. If you want to do this from a browser, you can craft an extension which could screen scrape visited sites without a problem. If you need a server-side solution, then use a headless browser such as [Phantom](http://phantomjs.org/) and control it by any other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can write a server side script to proxy your requests through
2. You can disable the check in some browsers by passing a commandline argument

Chromium:

```
chromium-browser --disable-web-security
```

See [Overriding Access-Control-Allow-Origin restriction in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/384871/overriding-access-control-allow-origin-restriction-in-google-chrome)

Comment: If you are going to use your server as a proxy to a JS app running in someone's browser, you might as well do the scrape from the server and only send the interesting parts back to the browser. This would minimize your bandwidth requirements. BUT ... the site being scraped might object and blacklist your server's IP (whether you proxy or scrape on the server).